# Xamarin Android Forms.Context obsolete - How to fix it in a dependent method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting a message saying FormsContext is obsolete.  I saw numerous suggestions on how to fix it but none apply to my case below:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SoundMethods))]
namespace J.Droid
{
    public class SoundMethods : ISoundMethods
    {
        public void IsDeviceSilent()
        {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this for my example?

Comment: Try Android.App.Application.Context instead of Forms.Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the Plugin.CurrentActivity from James Montemagno.

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity

Github: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

You have to initialize the plugin in your AppDelegate `OnCreate`:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

Then in your services (or in any class in the Android Project) you can get the current context with this:

```
var context = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the context in your constructor like this:

```
private Context _context;

public ContentPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

And then access it with the `_context` variable.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work with DependencyService.

Comment: This answer is for Renderers, the question is about Services to use with DI in the Forms project

Comment: @Arvindraja This works with DependencyService, I'm using it in my apps

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba It doesn't matter, this works perfectly fine in services, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to init and pass the Context from the MainActivity:

```
  static Context _context;

        public static void Init(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public void IsDeviceSilent()
        {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)_context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
        }
```

then, in `MainActivity`

```
SoundMethods.Init(this);
```

You can read more about in [here](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html)

Comment: I am confused.  It's a Xamarin Forms app and I don't have an Init.  Can you explain more?

Comment: A xamarin forms application, has a Xamarin.Android aplication. Where are you creating this class? In Android or Forms?

Comment: In the Android project of a Xamarin Forms app.

Comment: So, you have a MainActivity File, where you should do waht I told in the answer......